# React+SonarQube: Not able to add Const/let keyword to the declaration to make it explicit

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, sonarqube, es6-class, apexcharts

I am working on React component and ApexCharts. Recently, I got a Blocker issue in SonarQube **Add the "let", "const" or "var" keyword to this declaration of "Apex" to make it explicit**

My react component with ApexTheme looks like this

```js
const ApexTheme = () => {
   Apex = {         
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title:{
            align: 'center',
            margin: 20,
            style:{
                fontSize: '25px',
                fontWeight: '500',
            }
        },
  }
}

export default ApexTheme;
```

And in the main component, I am calling this ApexTheme() inside the class component

```js
class Component extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
                
        ApexTheme();
                
 }
```

It is working fine until I add const/let infront of the Apex in ApexTheme component. After adding const/let, none of the styles are applying to the charts/line.

I have also tried to remove the Apex variable completely. I got errors like **add (;) and  "Expression expected (declaration or statement expected)"**

[image]

How to get rid of this Blocker issue from sonarQube.

Thank you!

Comment: `export const ApexTheme = {....}` then directly use `<ReactApexChart options={ApexTheme} />`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried this also but it didn't work. ApexTheme file is common file which can be used in multiple components so we don't have any return in this component so there is no possibility to use <ReactApexChart options={ApexTheme}/> in ApexTheme component to share the options props.